# Attach Docker container to process in .NET Core / Visual Studio on Mac

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-mac

I have a docker-compose file containing multiple services. The compose file is part of a standalone git repository. Next to that I like to start my containers through the terminal by running `docker-compose up`. I know Visual Studio supports debugging Docker containers by adding Docker support. However, this requires the docker compose file to live in the same directory as the solution you are working in. Is there a way to start the containers via your terminal and attach Visual Studio for Mac to a process, so you can debug?